# Laundry Room outlet and light not working

Tags: electrical, wiring, switch, receptacle, light

[image][image]My overhead light and outlet in my laundry room are not working, all of the sudden. They are on the same breaker and nothing else in the house is on that breaker. I just replaced the light switch and the outlet, and replaced the breaker that controls the light/outlet. It still is not working. I have an inexpensive volt meter that lights up 110 in the 110 outlet when the light switch is off. Weirdly, the volt meter lights up 220 in the 110 outlet when the light switch is on (but the overhead light does not go on). Only other fact to mention is that there is a 220 outlet right next to the 110 outlet. The 220 outlet has not been used for many years (it was installed and used by a prior owner who were from Europe and had European appliances). This outlet shows 220 on the volt meter both when the light switch is off and when the light switch is on. Any help of what my issue is would be much appreciated. [image][image][image][image][image][image]

Comment: Did you check to see if there are any GFCI outlets in the ares that might have tripped?

Comment: Yes. I actually replaced 2 GFCI outlets (that were broken/stuck), thinking that would solve my problem, but it didn't. All other GFCI outlets in the house are working and not tripped.

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of the boxes involved?

Comment: Yes, photos may help uncover the problem

Comment: Pictures of the inside of the outlet box and the inside of the light switch box?  Or pictures of the inside of the breaker box?  Thanks.

Comment: @user107427 the former, yes

Comment: I added pictures of the inside of the light switch box (which has only one set of wires, with one black and one white, both of which are attached to the light switch). I also added pictures of the inside of the outlets box. Through the middle of the box is one set of wires which is powering the 220 volt outlet on the right side of the box. This set of wires has a white and a black and a copper ground -- all of which are attached to the 220 volt outlet.

Comment: There is another set of wires coming down through the top of the box. This set of wires has a white and a red and a black (no copper ground wire). From this set, the white and red are attached to the 110 volt outlet (on the left side of the box). The black from this set is capped off (and is not being used).

Comment: I posted photos. Please let me know your thoughts. Thanks @ThreePhaseEel

Comment: **This isn't the whole picture**.  There is only one cable to the switch box and it is a /2 with no ground.  The only /2 in your receptacle box has a ground and goes straight to the 240V receptacle.    There's clearly another box in play, or 2 circuits.  Tell us more about the breaker(s) associated with the switch, 120V outlet, and 240V outlet.

Comment: @harper see below additional info, and picture above that I added. Thanks.

Comment: Nope, we're still not accounting for all the wires.  assuming the groundless /2 in the new box you posted goes to the switch behind it, you have 2 pairs of wire in the conduit there- always-hot and neitral from supply, and switched-hot and neutral to the switched device.   That tells us nothing about where power for the receptacle comes from.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions for changes I can make so there is not extra power going to the 110 outlet when the light switch is turned on?  I would like the 110 volt outlet to stay 110 volts all the time (whether that light switch is on or off). Is there a modification I can make so the light switch only controls the overhead lighth fixture (and doesn't cause the 110 volt outlet to become a 220 volt outlet when turned on)?  Thanks b

Answer (score 1):

If you turn that switch on, it will run at 220v, probably your light runs at 120v (correct me if I'm wrong) which means that fluorescent, incandescent or led light will blow up after getting really bright depending of the type of light. Something must be wrong with the wiring in that switch-outlet.

Comment: Why would flipping the switch on cause it to run at 220, instead of 110 or 120?  That is confusing. And, why would it work fine for 15 years, and then suddenly not work?  Thanks.

Comment: If your meter is showing 220 you may have miswired something. the outlet with both prongs sideways is a 220v outlet, if you have 220 on a 120v lamp it will only last for 1/10 of a second or less but be very bright as John stated. You have changed the switch and outlet so my guess is you wired something differently than it was providing 220 at the light with the switch is on. Many baseboard heaters work this way only breaking 1 leg of the 220v line for example.

Comment: There are only two wires at the light switch. They were both attached to the old switch, so I attached both to the new switch. Does it matter which side the black wire goes into and which side the white wire goes into?  I tried to match it Up to how it was wired into the old switch, but maybe I got them flipped. Would this cause it to be 220 volts instead of 110 volts?  And would that cause the wall outlet to be impacted? Something happened to cause my light to stop working, and to cause my outlets to stop working properly. Thanks

Comment: For the 110 outlet, is that the proper wiring to have the white into one side and the red into the other side, with the black capped off?  I am guessing the black was used a while back for a second 110 outlet where the 220 outlet is now (not sure what would have been in the other side of the second 110 outlet). Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @Ed Beal for your reply. Are you able to answer my other questions?  Thanks.

Comment: Normally on a 120v system red is used as a switched hot this is not a code requirement but many electricians do this as well as manufacturers of electronic switches will have the switched lead as a red. On a multi wire branch circuit there are 2 hots a double pole breaker is used or a pair of handle tied breakers the black will be 1 hot and the red the other hot. If you measure the voltage from black to red there will be ~240v, I think this is what you have done in some way but I would need more voltage measurements to know for sure.

Comment: Why would it suddenly not work? **Backstabs**. It's SOP for backstabs to randomly fail open one day.

Answer (score 1):

At first glance, it seems like the switch is putting out-of-phase power onto the neutral terminal of the 110v outlet. The only reason I can imagine someone doing this is as an attempt to turn an outlet into a switchable 110v/220v outlet, possibly originally intended for the 220v outlet (I'm not familiar with European appliances, maybe some are supposed to run on 110 but use the same plug style?)

I'm also not sure how the 220v outlet reads 220v with only one hot wire to it.

Look around for another junction box, probably with a blank plate. I feel like we're not getting the full picture here, and someone switched some wires accidentally while doing work. Could possibly be in the box behind the light as well.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99250/discussion-on-answer-by-nate-laundry-room-outlet-and-light-not-working).

Comment: @Michael Karas did you delete some of the comments and answers to my questions?  Thanks!

Comment: We move extended strings of comments to the chat room where such ongoing discussions belong. No answers were deleted.

Comment: @Michael Karas That's too bad.  Once you moved it to chat, everyone stopped responding, and I have not resolved my issue. Are you the person who run's this site?

Comment: Sorry I haven't received notifications since theN